# Search by content type using Search API in REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-addin, rest

I have two content types, `softs ct` and `softs ct page` having parent content types `item` and `page` .

I managed to display results from custom list which is having `softs ct` but it doesn't display results from `softs ct page`.

I have tried with 
`ContentType:'softs*'` but it only shows results from one content type. How can I get from both content types?

Here is my search query

```
var query = appweburl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:softs*'&selectproperties='Title,DueDate,ExpiryDate'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'";
```

Comment: how about only 'softs ct'?

Comment: no it dont give results . i have tested on search query tool also . when i choose the source parameter "local sharepoint results" it display results but just from softs ct not from softs ct page.... and when i change the source to "Pages" then it display from 'soft ct page'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that your `softs ct page` results have been crawled?

Also, you might want to try using the `OR` operator to specify both ContentTypes on a Result source and then reference it on your URL:

```
{{searchterms} ContentType:A OR ContentType:B}

var query = appweburl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:softs*'&selectproperties='Title,DueDate,ExpiryDate'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&sourceid='40f080a5-da63-4dce-b33a-fdad0dc83d1c'";
```

You can also try adding SPContentType to your refinementfilters:

```
var query = appweburl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='yoursearchterm'&selectproperties='Title,DueDate,ExpiryDate'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&sourceid='40f080a5-da63-4dce-b33a-fdad0dc83d1c'&refinementfilters='SPContentType:(%22Download%22)'";
```

You might need to specify a QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl on that URL:

```
QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl='spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml'
```

More on that on [Waldek's post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api-anonymous-users/).

You might find this tool useful:

https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hei i have tried in search tool but seems not working . I have same parameters in both content types soo its already been crawled. strange thing is it display results but just from one content type which is "soft ct" . can u share with me any screenshot from query tool how did u try to get results from both content types.

Comment: thank u Lucas i made that work with source id and query text as contenttype:soft*